# position fixed div over scrollable div - can't scroll

Tags: css, html, scroll

I have a fixed div over a div that I want to scroll. When my mouse is over the fixed div I can not scroll the div. Is there anyway around this?

```
#scroll {
  width:660px;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:scroll
}

#fixed {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  background:red;

}
```

http://codepen.io/garethj/pen/PpPmdJ

Comment: `pointer-events:none` (go check browser compatibility)

Comment: thanks - unfortunately I need a link in my fixed div

Comment: you could give your fixed div 20px right: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpaomW although your text will still be hidden under the fixed div.  I would reduce the height of the scroll div by the height of the fixed div and then add that as margin bottom: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMmged

Comment: nice idea, but does not work for mouse wheel scrolls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `pointer-events:none;` this allow you to `scroll`, even when your cursor is on `#fixed div`

```
#fixed {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  background:red;
  pointer-events:none; /*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: thanks - unfortunately I need a link in my fixed div

Comment: thank you - #fixed > a {pointer-events:auto} solved the problem

Comment: Welcome @user1059511 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give `#fixed` the following `width` declaration:

```
width: calc(100% - 16px);
```